# How can I write Python script result to S3 instead of local drive?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

#Im working on below script to pull the information of AWS ec2 instances with details.
#What it does now is that it pull the information that I am after and create a csv file in the same patch of the script. I am working on expanding this to make it a Lambda function to pull down the information from all AWS accounts and instead of creating CSV on local machine push the data (CSV) format to S3 location.
#Now challenge ahead that I need help on how to modify the script to be able to write to S3 bucket instead of writing to the local drive?

```
import boto3
import csv
from pprint import pprint

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='#ProfileName')
ec2_re=session.resource(service_name="ec2",region_name="ap-southeast-2")
ec2_cli=session.client(service_name="ec2")

fo=open('EC2_Details.csv','w',newline='')
data_obj=csv.writer(fo) data_obj.writerow(["InstanceID","InstanceType","InstanceName","InstanceLunchTime","Instance_Private_IP","InstanceState","InstanceTags"])

cnt=1
response = ec2_cli.describe_instances()
for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        data_obj.writerow([instance["InstanceId"], instance["InstanceType"], instance["KeyName"], instance["LaunchTime"], instance["PrivateIpAddress"], instance["State"]["Name"], instance["Tags"]])
        cnt+=1

fo.close()
```

Thank you

Comment: for lambda functions the 'local' directory to write to would be '/tmp/EC2_Details.csv', then you can use @Floh's method to upload to S3. the path here be '/tmp/EC2_Details.csv' as well

Answer (score 0):

Trivial way, you upload the file you created on disk.

There are advanced way that avoid writing on disk, you can find them on SO.

```py
import boto3
import csv
from pprint import pprint

#Creating Session With Boto3.
session = boto3.Session(
    profile_name="your profile",
)



session = boto3.Session(profile_name='#ProfileName')
ec2_re=session.resource(service_name="ec2",region_name="ap-southeast-2")
ec2_cli=session.client(service_name="ec2")

fo=open('EC2_Details.csv','w',newline='')
data_obj=csv.writer(fo) data_obj.writerow(["InstanceID","InstanceType","InstanceName","InstanceLunchTime","Instance_Private_IP","InstanceState","InstanceTags"])

cnt=1
response = ec2_cli.describe_instances()
for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        data_obj.writerow([instance["InstanceId"], instance["InstanceType"], instance["KeyName"], instance["LaunchTime"], instance["PrivateIpAddress"], instance["State"]["Name"], instance["Tags"]])
        cnt+=1

fo.close()


#Creating S3 Resource From the Session.
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket("your-bucket-name")
bucket.upload_file('EC2_Details.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Floh,
That should work if I want to run the script locally but if I want to make it a lambda function I dont know if this still works?
Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: This will perfectly work also in lambda. You can use /tmp for local storage.